# VB.Net List of Controls

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I want to get a list of all controls; I managed to do that in the code below; the issue is that this does list the controls outside containers only. I want to get list of all controls including those inside containers (such as controls inside TabControl). My Question is: How to do this in VB.Net?

```
Sub ListAllControls()
    Me.RichTextBox1.Clear()
    Dim MekdamCTL As Control
    For Each MekdamCTL In Me.Controls
        Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText("Control: " & MekdamCTL.Name & Environment.NewLine)
    Next
    Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText("How to include ALL Controls in ALL Containers, such as Controls in TabControl ??")
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for help and/or comments.

Comment: You can use recursion but you don't have to.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little more complex than you need, but the following function returns all the controls of any given type and optionally searches any embedded containers

```
''' <summary>Get all Controls of a specified type within a container and optionally any embedded containers</summary>
''' <typeparam name="ctrlType">The type of Control to be searched for (must inherit from Control)</typeparam>
''' <param name="parent">The top level container</param>
''' <param name="searchContainers">True if embedded containers are to be searched</param>
''' <returns>IEnumerable with all Controls of the specified type that were found</returns>
Function GetControlsOfType(Of ctrlType As Control)(parent as Control, searchContainers As Boolean) As IEnumerable(Of ctrlType)
    Dim ctrls As New List(Of ctrlType)
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls 
        If TypeOf ctrl Is ctrlType Then ctrls.Add(DirectCast(ctrl, ctrlType))
        If searchContainers AndAlso ctrl.Controls.Count > 0 Then ctrls.AddRange(GetControlsOfType(Of ctrlType)(ctrl, searchContainers))
    Next
    Return ctrls
End Function
```

If you want to list all controls of any type, you can call it like this:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In GetControlsOfType(Of Control)(Me, True)
    Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText("Control: " & ctrl.Name & vbCrLf)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a recursive function that you can call from your main form

```
Public Sub ListControls(coll As Control.ControlCollection)
    for each ctr in coll
       Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText("Control: " & ctr.Name & Environment.NewLine)
       if ctr.Controls.Count > 0 Then
          ListControls(ctr.Controls)
       End if
    Next
End Sub
```

Call it from your main form

```
ListControls(Me.Controls)
```

Comment: I got my answer; but I am just curious, this code did not list the "Inside Controls" ?? Can you please check ? it gave identical results to my posted code in my question.

Comment: All right, it doesn't print the name of the control container, fixed now.

Comment: A recursive method works but you don't 'need' recursion.

Comment: @dbasnett you are correct. Just following a prefixed line of thought without thinking out of the box. Upvoting your answer because is the best

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
    'this loop will get all the controls on the form
    'no matter what the level of container nesting

    Dim ctrl As Control = Me.GetNextControl(Me, True)
    Do Until ctrl Is Nothing
        RichTextBox1.AppendText("Control: " & ctrl.Name & Environment.NewLine)
        ctrl = Me.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
    Loop
```

With this method there is no need for checking or recursion.

Answer (score 0):

May This Can Be Used:

```
Private Sub frmWRMenu_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated

Dim k As New List(Of String)
     Dim myNumber = 0
     Dim myCtrl As Control = Me
Repeat:
    For a = 1 To myCtrl.Controls.Count
        k.Add(myCtrl.Controls(a - 1).Name)
        Debug.Print(myCtrl.Controls(a - 1).Name)
    Next
    If (myNumber + 1) <= k.Count Then
        myCtrl = Me.Controls.Find(k(myNumber ), True)(0)
        myNumber += 1
        GoTo Repeat
    End If
End Sub
```